# How can I differentiate stack and heap nodes of vm_area_struct in kernel space?

Tags: linux-kernel

In kernel space using pseudo driver I am trying to implements maps file of a process in that how to differentiate stack and heap nodes in virtual memory nodes.

```c
long myIoctl(struct file* fp1, unsigned int pid, unsigned long b)
{
    struct module* mod = NULL;
    struct task_struct *my_task = NULL;
    struct vm_area_struct * vm_area = NULL;
    my_task = current;
    vm_area = my_task -> mm -> mmap;
    mod = THIS_MODULE;


    while (vm_area) {
        printk ("%p-%p  ", (int *)(vm_area -> vm_start), (int *) (vm_area -> vm_end));
        printk ("%d   ", vm_area -> vm_flags);
        if ((vm_area -> vm_flags) & VM_READ) {
            printk("r");
        }
        if ((vm_area -> vm_flags) & VM_WRITE) {
            printk("w");
        } else {
            printk ("_");
        }
        if ((vm_area -> vm_flags) & VM_EXEC) {
            printk("x");
        } else {
            printk ("_");
        }
        if ((vm_area -> vm_flags) & VM_SHARED) {
            printk("s");
        } else {
            printk ("p");
        }

        printk ("  %.8lx  ", (vm_area -> vm_pgoff) << 12 );
        if (vm_area -> vm_file) {
            printk ("%ld  ", vm_area -> vm_file -> f_inode -> i_ino);
            printk ("%u\n", MAJOR(vm_area -> vm_file -> f_inode -> i_rdev));
            printk (":%u\n", MINOR(vm_area -> vm_file -> f_inode -> i_rdev));
        } else {
            printk ("0\n");
        }
        vm_area = vm_area -> vm_next;

    }

    return 0;
}
```

[image: in the image see stack and heap sections]

Answer (score 1):

The OS already implements /proc/< pid >/maps which shows all VMAs of that process, including the stack,heap and of course the mmap-ed ones.

If you want to check from where all these information fill you can check kernel source code,the The relevant code (to look up VMAs of a given PID) seems to be here: **`fs/proc/task_mmu.c`** .

And, yes indeed, the "[heap]" is marked by this code snippet from the above src file (kernel ver 3.10.24):

**fs/proc/task_mmu.c:show_map_vma()**

```
... 
if (vma->vm_start <= mm->brk && vma->vm_end >= mm->start_brk) 
{ 
    name = "[heap]"; goto done; } 
...
```

And one more thing if you want to check start-end address of particular segment, Do check The **mm_struct** is defined in . you will get following thing :-

```
struct mm_struct{
......
    unsigned long start_code, end_code, start_data, end_data;
    unsigned long start_brk, brk, start_stack;
......
}
```

1. start_code, end_code The start and end address of the code section;
2. start_data, end_data The start and end address of the data section;
3. start_brk, brk The start and end address of the heap;
4. start_stack Predictably enough, the start of the stack region;